# Frequent crashes with Intel i915 and second HDMI monitor

Tags: release-loki

elementary OS is a gorgeous operating system, to the point where I have donated multiple times to it. However, there is something driving me nuts that  will ultimately lead me to abandon it if not fixed.

I have a Samsung Series 9 laptop (NP900X3B). This laptop has an Intel i915 graphics card.

Every time I connect a second monitor to it, using the micro HDMI port, and lock / unlock my screen, I get a kernel crash and complete freeze of the system that forces me to reboot it.

I always work with two monitors and always lock my desktop when I walk away from my desk. As a result, since I installed elementary OS, I'm rebooting my laptop 3-6 times per day during business hours.

Here is the version of the kernel I'm currently running:
Linux galaxy 4.10.0-27-generic #30~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 29 16:07:46 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Here is the output of lshw showing the information about the VGA controller and the kernel module in use.

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [144d:c0cd]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

Here is the crash information on kernel.log: https://pastebin.com/ffhDQAM3

When the crashes happen I see these messages on the screen:
[drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
[drm:ironlake_crtc_enable [i915]] *ERROR* mode set failed: pipe A stuck

I have used the Intel tools to update the i915 module / driver to its latest version, as per: https://pastebin.com/hguNVG3W

Please note that I run Ubuntu 16.04 in this laptop before and never had these issues. I thought for a moment that the kernel upgrade from 4.8 to 4.10 could be the cause. I downgraded the kernel to 4.8 to test this hypothesis, but had no success, so I switched back to 4.10.

Any ideas on how I could fix it?

Cheers,
Bruno